# GLTF object are grounding when loaded

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, gltf, sceneform

On loading GLTF files from the server, objects are not taking the origin but counting as position (0,0,0) from the bottom,
but when the same file we check in blender all the objects are in correct order.

Do we have to manually set the vertex location for all meshes in GLTF's, to be the origin because their relative transforms are not being respected by Sceneform.

I have tried using setRecenterMode() but didn't work.

[image]

here is my code below

```
 hair_render = ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                    this,
                    Uri.parse(hair_gltf),
                    RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                    .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.NONE)
                    .build())

            .setRegistryId(hair_gltf)
            .build();
    body_render = ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                    this,
                    Uri.parse(body_gltf),
                    RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                    .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.NONE)
                    .build())

            .setRegistryId(body_gltf)
            .build();

    top_render = ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                    this,
                    Uri.parse(top_gltf),
                    RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                    .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.NONE)
                    .build())
            .setRegistryId(top_gltf)
            .build();

    CompletableFuture.allOf(
            body_render,
            top_render,
            hair_render)
            .handle((notUsed, throwable) -> {
              if (throwable != null) {
                DemoUtils.displayError(this, "Unable to load renderable", throwable);
                return null;
              }

              try {

                body = body_render.get();
                top = top_render.get();
                hair = hair_render.get();

                // Everything finished loading successfully.
                hasFinishedLoading = true;

              } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                DemoUtils.displayError(this, "Unable to load renderable", ex);
              }

              return null;
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried opening this model in a few other viewers, like http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ or http://sandbox.babylonjs.com/? If the model appears correctly there, you may want to file a bug on Sceneform. If not, you may want to file a bug on the exporter.

Comment: Yes, I have tried different viewers and it comes perfectly fine, also have filed a bug in sceneform. I guess they have these issue but till then am looking out for some workaround for this.